# inverses of fundamental units of real quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$
be a real quadratic field and let $\nu$
be its fundamental unit
(notice that $\nu$
is uniquely determined in this case).
I want to know whether or not it is always the case that
$$\nu^{-1}=\pm\overline\nu.$$
I notice that this checks out for the first several quadratic fields
(i.e. low values for square free $d\in\mathbb{N}$
with $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$),
but is it always the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, always the (Galois) norm (from number field $k$ to $\mathbb Q$) of a unit is a unit in $\mathbb Z$, so is $\pm 1$. In the case of a quadratic field extension, the norm of $\alpha$ is $\alpha\cdot \alpha^\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the non-trivial (Galois) automorphism.

Comment: Great, and thanks for that clear justification of it!

Comment: :) .............